# Tangent, Normal, Binormal Vectors, Curvature and Torsion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

a) Find the unit tangent, normal, binormal vectors **T** **N** **B** and the curvature and torsion at a general point on the following curves;

**r** = $t$**i** + $\frac{t^2}{2}$**j** + $\frac{t^3}{3}$**k**,    ($0 \le t \le 1$).

(Note: the torsion $\tau$ is defined as $d$**B**$/ds$ = $\tau$**N**)

b) Determine the point where the curve has the minimum torsion, and write the form of the
osculating plane and osculating circle of the curve through that point.

I feel comfortable with part *a*, my only problem is dealing with part *b*.  Not entirely sure how to find the minimum torsion and go about the rest of the problem.  Any help and/or solution would be much appreciated.  Feel free to answer part *a* as well, it would be nice to compare answers and see if I'm actually doing these problems properly.

Comment: Take the derivative, set it to $0$, find your critical values and start testing those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a)

Computing $\bf T$, $\bf N$ and $\bf B$ from their definition might be messy.  But using

$$\kappa  = \frac{\| r' \times r'' \|}{\left\| {r'} \right\|^3}$$

$$\tau  = \frac{\left( {r' \times r''} \right)\cdot r'''}{\left\| {r' \times r''} \right\|^2}$$

Should be simple enough and then use the Frenet-Serret equations to back calculate $\bf N$ and $\bf B$.  I think  $\bf T$ is simple enough by a direct computation.

For part (b)
I got

$$\tau  = \frac{2}{t^4+4t^2+1}$$

(Double check I did it quickly).  To find the minimum take the derivative 
and set it to zero and solve for t.  And you get t = CP ( the critical 
point).

And then the osculating circle...
You must have some formula or form of a circle to use here.  You know
that the point 
${\bf r}(CP)$ is on the circle and that the radius is 
$$R = \frac{1}{\kappa(CP)}$$

The osculating circle is in the plane of ${\bf T}$ and  ${\bf N}$.  So one formula for your circle could be...

$${\bf r}(t) = R{\bf N}(CP)+ {\bf r}(CP) + {\bf N}(CP) \cdot \cos(t) +
 {\bf T}(CP) \cdot \sin(t)
$$

Check your book or notes, there may be another equation.